# Como preencher valores faltantes em um dataframe no R?

Tags: r, data, dataframe

Eu possuo um dataframe que contém os seguintes dados:

```
DTOBITO     n
2018-01-01  4
2018-01-02  2
2018-01-03  2
2018-01-04  1
2018-01-05  3
2018-01-07  2
2018-01-08  3
2018-01-09  1
2018-01-10  2
2018-01-11  1
2018-01-12  2
2018-01-15  3
2018-01-16  1
2018-01-17  2
2018-01-18  2
2018-01-19  2
2018-01-20  4
2018-01-21  3
2018-01-22  2
2018-01-23  2
2018-01-24  5
2018-01-25  7
2018-01-26  3
2018-01-27  2
2018-01-30  1
2018-01-31  1
```

Porém alguns dias não possuem o numero de mortes naquele dia (coluna n), o dia 2018-01-06, é um exemplo.
Queria saber como preencher esses dias que estão sem mortes com o valor 0.

Answer (score 3):

Em uma série temporal quando não houverem registros de observações em pontos no tempo pode-se usar a função [`pad()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/padr/html/pad.html) que preenche lacunas em variáveis ​​temporais incompletas. A função `pad()` se encontra no pacote [`padr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html).

Substitua todos os valores ausentes em colunas especificadas usando a função [`fill_by_value()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/padr/html/fill_by_value.html) que se encontra no pacote [`padr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html).

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)

df <- structure(list(DTOBITO = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", 
"2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-09", 
"2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-16", 
"2018-01-17", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21", 
"2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-26", 
"2018-01-27", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31"), n = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))

# Converte DTOBITO para objetos de classe Date.
df$DTOBITO <- as.Date(df$DTOBITO)

#Preenche as lacunas temporais e substitui os valores ausentes por 0.
df %>% 
  pad(interval = "day", end_val = tail(.$DTOBITO, n=1)) %>% 
  fill_by_value(value = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)

dat_time <- structure(list(DTOBITO = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", 
"2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-09", 
"2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-16", 
"2018-01-17", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21", 
"2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-26", 
"2018-01-27", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31"), n = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))


# coverter data para formato lubridate
dat_time$DTOBITO = ymd(dat_time$DTOBITO)

# Criar uma sequencia continua de dias para verificar quais dias estao faltando
dias_con <- seq(min(dat_time$DTOBITO), max(dat_time$DTOBITO), by = 'day')

# Quais dias estao faltando?
dias_miss <- dias_con[!dias_con %in% dat_time$DTOBITO]

# adicionar os dias
dat_time = rbind(
  dat_time,
  data.frame(
    DTOBITO = dias_miss,
    n = 0
  )
)
```

Comment: Usei o seus dados na minha resposta. OK?

Answer (score 2):

Com `tidyr` (parte do `tidyverse`) pode usar `complete` com `full_seq`. Vou usar uma versão diferente do seu exemplo para facilitar a visualização:

```
library(tidyr)

dados <- read.csv(text = '
  DTOBITO,n
  2018-01-27,4
  2018-01-28,2
  2018-01-30,3
  2018-02-02,2',
  colClasses = c("Date", "integer"))

complete(dados, DTOBITO = full_seq(DTOBITO, 1), fill = list(n = 0))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   DTOBITO        n
#>   <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-27     4
#> 2 2018-01-28     2
#> 3 2018-01-29     0
#> 4 2018-01-30     3
#> 5 2018-01-31     0
#> 6 2018-02-01     0
#> 7 2018-02-02     2
```

Se nos seus dados DTOBITO não estiver como formato Date, use `as.Date` para converter primeiro. Por exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)
librarry(tidyr)

dados %>%
  mutate(DTOBITO = as.Date(DTOBITO)) %>%
  complete(DTOBITO = full_seq(DTOBITO, 1), fill = list(n = 0))
```